# How to save the tinyMCE editor content to mysql using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using TinyMCE editor to create posts in my app.

When I click `save` nothing happens.

```
<?php  
$title = "Tambah Film";
include 'koneksi.php';
include 'header.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $judul = htmlentities($_POST['judul']);
    $nama_kat = htmlentities($_POST['nama_kat']);
    $nama_tag = htmlentities($_POST['nama_tag']);
    $konten = htmlentities($_POST['konten']);
    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `konten`(`judul`,`nama_kat`,`nama_tag`,`konten`)
    VALUES (:judul,:nama_kat,:nama_tag,:konten)");
    $query->bindParam(":judul", $judul);
    $query->bindParam(":nama_kat", $nama_kat);
    $query->bindParam(":nama_tag", $nama_tag);
    $query->bindParam(":konten", $konten);
    $query->execute();
}
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tag");
$query->execute();
$data = $query->fetchAll();
$query2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM kategori");
$query2->execute();
$data2 = $query2->fetchAll();?>
```

my full code https://github.com/jazuly/ahp/blob/master/post.php

Comment: First of all check, are you getting the html from tinymce editor content or not ?

Comment: put method="POST" in <form> tag. 

btw, I think you also have to include tinymce javascript first in order to use it and, it's always good practice to place javascripts at the bottom of html right before closing body tag.